What number of dice rolled maximizes the probability of getting exactly $k$ more sixes than fives? Hypothesis: $n=3k^2$.
Question

Let $k\in \mathbb N$. Prove/disprove that
$$
f(n) = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n-k}{2} \right\rfloor}  \binom{n}{j} \binom{n-j}{j+k} 4^{-k-2j}
$$
is maximized for $n=3k^2$.

Context:
I came up with this when doodling with the following probability problem: What is the amount of dice thrown that makes it the most probable to achieve exactly $k$ more sixes than fives. Call this number $n_{\max}$. I got curious as (for all the values of $k$ I tried) the maximum point of $f$ as real function was near an integer and what more given by the simple formula $3k^2$.
(Desmos calculates $f$ for real $n$ and shows the maximum point.)
My tries
We can ignore $4^{-k}$. Let's write the summand as
$$
\frac{n!}{16^j j!(j+k)!(n-2j-k)!}
$$
I thought about using Stirling approximation (although I wouldn't know how to justify it even if I got a solution with it). And in the middle it's like $n-2j-k \approx \frac{n}{3}$, so
$$
\frac{n!}{(n-2j-k)!} \approx 3^n \sqrt{3} \left( \frac{n}{3e}\right)^{2j+k}
$$
And then take the derivative but that seem cumbersome too...
Intuitive Idea: Difference of sixes and fives is a random walk with probability $\frac{1}{6}$ of going up, $\frac{1}{6}$ of going down and $\frac{2}{3}$ of staying in place. So maybe the factor $3 = \frac{6}{2}$ (and more generally $\frac{D}{2}$, see comments) comes from that we need to have this many rolls to have $k^2$ effective rolls (fives or sixes). And then it is squared because the random walk "grows like square root".

For the largest term, the ratio from one term to the next is $1$, so $16j(j+k)=(n-2j-k+1)(n-2j-k+2)$

If you change the number of sides on a die, how does the $3k^2$ change?

@Empy2 It seems to be (at least close to) $\frac{D}{2}k^2$.

The number $3n^2$ is the answer if you treat the binomials as correlated normal variables
Let $f_i=1$ if roll $i$ is a 5, and zero otherwise.  Let $s_i=1$ if that roll is a six, and zero otherwise.  Then $f_i^2=f_i$ because they are both $0$ or both $1$, but $f_is_i=0$ because no roll is both a 5 and a 6.
$$E(f_i)=E(s_i)=\frac16\\
E(f_i^2)=E(s_i^2)=\frac16\\
E(f_is_i)=0\\
E(f_if_j)=E(s_is_j)=E(f_is_j)=\frac1{36}(i\ne j)$$Let $F$ be the number of $5$s and $S$ the number of $6$s.  Now
$$E(F)=\sum_iE(f_i)=n/6=E(S)\\  
E(F^2)=\sum_i\sum_jE(f_if_j)=\frac16n+\frac1{36}(n^2-n)\\E(FS)=0n+\frac1{36}(n^2-n)
$$
The correlation matrix of $F$ and $S$ is built, for example, from $E(F^2)-E(F)^2$ and $E(FS)-E(F)E(S)$.  It is
$$\Sigma =\left[\begin{array}[cc]&
\frac{5n}{36}&\frac{-n}{36}\\
\frac{-n}{36}&\frac{5n}{36}
\end{array}\right]$$
whose inverse is
$$\Sigma^{-1}=\frac3{2n}\left[
\begin{array}[cc]&
5&1\\1&5\end{array}
\right]$$
Let the vector $v=(F ,S)=(x-\frac k2,x+\frac k2)$, so there are $k$ more sixes than fives.  Then $$v\Sigma^{-1}v^t=\frac3{2n}(12x^2+2k^2)$$
The multivariate PDF from the page I linked is $$\frac Cn\exp(-\frac9nx^2-\frac3{2n}k^2)$$
for some constant $C$.  Integrate over all values of $x$ and the PDF for $k$ is
$$\frac{D}{\sqrt{n}}\exp(-\frac{3}{2n}k^2)$$
To find the highest value as a function of $n$, differentiate $d/dn$ and set to $0$.  It helps if you take logs first.  The answer is $n=3k^2$.
